# my java socket application

Tags: java, sockets, database-connection

I tried to make a simple port scanning programs from java and I make it like this:

```
    package PortScanning;

/**
 *
 * @author fonts
 */
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class port {
 static int scan=20;

 public void load() {
 try {
 if (scan <= 587)
{
 System.out.print(" Scanning...");
 scan++;
 Socket gw = new Socket("127.0.0.1",scan);
 System.out.println(scan + "\t\t opened");
 port lagi=new port();
 lagi.load();
}
 else
{
 System.out.println("\n—————————————–\n—————————————–\n Finish... \n\n");
}
}
 catch (Exception e)
{
 System.out.println(scan + "\t\t closed");
 port lagi=new port();
 lagi.load();
}
}
 public static void main(String[]args)
{
System.out.print(" Try Scanning \n—————————————–\n—————————————–\n\n");
scan--;
port panggil=new port();
panggil.load();
}
}
```

but I wanted to ask how the process of scanning ports on the capture of data that I previously inserted into the database, so will the system work becomes automatic scanning of the database table before I make like this:

```
=================
ip        | port
=================
127.0.0.1 | 80
127.0.0.1 | 25
etc.      | etc.
=================
```

I hope anyone can help my problem
and thanks a lot

Comment: What on earth is your question?  I can't tell.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Read what you wrote aloud: _"I wanted to ask how the process of scanning ports on the capture of data that I previously inserted into the database, so will the system work becomes automatic scanning of the database table before I make like this."_ Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: It looks as though `load()` calls `load()` with a new object... I'm not sure this is a desirable operation...

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, I mean ,scanning port and ip taken from the database that I created, so the process of port scanning is taken from the database that I created

Answer (score 0):

For accessing databases in Java, one can use JDBC. Have a look at [Jdbc-Tutorial](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/) for getting started.

Concerning your port scanning program, you can follow the following path for building it :

1. Open database `Connection`
2. Get the list of ports (with ip) to scan from database with a `Statement`
3. For each ports found, scan it with its associated ip; use `ResultSet`
4. Close `Statement` and database `Connection`

Good luck !